# New to Spark. - getting java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Spark.  Just installed version 1.6.0 in my laptop (Ubuntu) and proceeded with an example using the phyton's shell (pyspark).  However, I cannot figure out what this error is telling me.  Can you please help? any help is appreciated.

```
>>> lines = sc.textFile("spark-1.6.0/README.md")
>>> lines.count()
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ricky/spark-1.6.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1004, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/home/ricky/spark-1.6.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 995, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "/home/ricky/spark-1.6.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 869, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/home/ricky/spark-1.6.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/home/ricky/spark-1.6.0/python/lib/py4j-0.9-    src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/home/ricky/spark-1.6.0/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in   deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ricky/spark-1.6.0/python/lib/py4j-0.9-   src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, **in get_return_value**
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling     z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at     org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.serveIterator(PythonRDD.scala:637)
        at    org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
        at  org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)   
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java    :43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> > > 

Answer (score 0):

Ricky,

Looks like you want to figure out how to debug the issue

1) First go to your conf directory and copy log4j.properties.template file to log4j.properties and in that file, change log level to DEBUG log4j.rootCategory=**DEBUG**, console and restart your pyspark shell, you should start seeing lot more debug info

2) In your code change
lines = sc.textFile("README.md")
lines.count()

When i execute these steps in my local, it works this is the log i see
    16/03/09 08:16:29 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_0
    16/03/09 08:16:29 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_0 is  StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1)
    16/03/09 08:16:29 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting block broadcast_0 from memory
    16/03/09 08:16:29 DEBUG HadoopRDD: Creating new JobConf and caching it for later re-use
    16/03/09 08:16:29 DEBUG : address: SUNILPATIL.local/10.250.57.78 isLoopbackAddress: false, with host 10.250.57.78 SUNILPATIL.local
    16/03/09 08:16:29 DEBUG FileInputFormat: Time taken to get FileStatuses: 8
    16/03/09 08:16:29 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
    16/03/09 08:16:29 DEBUG FileInputFormat: Total # of splits generated by getSplits: 2, TimeTaken: 15
    16/03/09 08:16:29 DEBUG ClosureCleaner: +++ Cleaning closure  (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12) +++
    16/03/09 08:16:29 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:  + declared fields: 2

Spark uses Hadoop IO for reading files and when the FileInputFormat starts it tries to connect back to the local loopback address. That could be the problem in your case. If not post the detailed stack trace

Sunil

Comment: Thanks Sunil.  I will try the DEBUG and update with findings.

Comment: Sunil, do you think I may need to set SPARK_LOCAL_IP ?   See warning message when pyspark's shell starts.   BTW: I tried to post the full stack error now that Debug is ON (thanks) but it is too long for this forum. :-( 

16/03/14 23:31:06 WARN Utils: Your hostname, ubuntu resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.2.227 instead (on interface enp11s0)
16/03/14 23:31:06 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address

Comment: Yes give it a try. You can find more information at https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/connectivity_issues.html

Comment: I no longer get the warning about the loopback address but unfortunately the original error remains. It does seems like the code is executed but at the end there is that error **in get_return_value**:

File "/home/ricky/spark-1.6.0/python/lib/py4j-0.9-   src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, **in get_return_value**
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling     z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

Comment: I will try uninstalling spark and re-installing it.

Comment: Found the problem. Here it is in case someone else is wondering about this same error.  In my case, it was related to a misconfiguration in my /etc/hosts. I previously had '127.0.0.1 localhost' but once I changed that IP to the actual machine's IP the problem was gone.  Thanks Sunil for looking at this.